# Display HTML content in UILabel

Tags: objective-c

How to display html content in label.
Bellow link is how my label display html content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1TKP.png

I also try using this code.

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> Some html string </body></html>"; 

NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: The code you post should work. What's wrong exactly?

Comment: it display <li> tag in text. you can check link that I share.plz suggest me for that

Comment: It shouldn't, could you share the real `htmlString`? Does `attrStr.string` (you can print it) show theses `<li>` tags?

Comment: Hear, the string that I get from URL.


  "The popular Mini Pashli holds your daily essentials. With signature side zip-pleats, this style is often worn fanned-open and crossbody via detachable shoulder strap. Just pinch to open the push-lock padlock. <ul> <li>100% Full Grain Leather</li> <li>6.5"H x 8.5"W x 3"D</li> <li>16.5" - 22" Adjustable Shoulder Strap</li> <li>Fully Lined</li> <li>Dust Bag included</li> <li>Imported</li> <li>AE17-0226SKC</li> </ul>"


There are any other option to display this text

Comment: `NSLog(@"[attrStr string]: %@", [attrStr string]);` from your `htmlString` doesn't give the html tags. Do you do at some point `myLabel.text = htmlString` or something like that instead of `myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;`?

Comment: Thank you, after using myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;  it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your html string which was in image.I got the solution

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  NSString * htmlString = @"Description: The popular Mini Pashili holds your daily essentials. With signature side zip-pleats,this style is often worn fanned-open and cross body via detachable shoulder strap.Just pinch to open the push-lock padlock.<ul><li>100%Full Grain Leather</li><li>6.5”H x 8.5”W x 3”D</li><li>16.5”-22” Adjustable Shoulder Starp</li><li>Fully Lined</li><li>Dust Bag included</li><li>Imported</li><li>AE17-0226SKC</li></ul>";
  NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
  UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
  myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 350, 300);
  myLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
  myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
  [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
}
```

Now the solution is

[image]